# Using radio buttons within javascript for a calculation

Tags: javascript, html

I've been working at this for a few hours and I cannot, for the life of my figure out how to do this.

So, I wanted to make a calculation in java-script (on the back of HTML).  And I was wondering how I could get the radio button to chance the value of a number of vars.  E.G  (female radio button checked, var a = 10, var x = 20, etc..., but if male radio button checked, var a = 34,var x = 32, etc...)

also along with this I wanted to know if i could do a long sum like for example (bmr = a + (x * weight) + (y * height) - (z * age)).  Then finally diplay all this information on a different text field.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;         charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="jstest.js">

        </SCRIPT>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form action="" method="post" name="caloriecalc">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Age:</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="age" size="5" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Gender:</td>
                    <td>
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" />Male</label>
                        <br />
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" />Female</label>
                        <br />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Weight:</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="weight" size="7" />KG</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Height:</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="height" size="7" />CM</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label>Exercise Level:</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="activity">
                            <option value="1.2">Sedentary (little or no exercise)</option>
                            <option value="1.375">Lightly active (exercise/sports 1-3 days/wk</option>
                            <option value="1.55">Mod. active (exercise/sports 3-5 days/wk)</option>
                            <option value="1.725">Very active (exercise/sports 6-7 days/wk)</option>
                            <option value="1.9">Extr. Active (daily exercise/sports & physical job))</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>
                        <input name="calc" type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="validate()" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
            </table>
        </form>
        <table width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td width="50%" align="right">BMR</td>
                <td width="50%" id="bmr"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>

</html>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function validate() {
    var age = document.caloriecalc.age.value;
    var weight = document.caloriecalc.weight.value;
    var height = document.caloriecalc.height.value;

    if (age <= 0 || parseInt(age) != age) {
        alert("Please enter a valid age.");
    } else if (weight <= 0 || isNaN(Number(weight))) {
        alert("Please enter a valid weight.");
    } else if (height <= 0 || isNaN(Number(height))) {
        alert("Please enter a valid height.");

    } else { //all the data has been validated
        calculate(parseInt(age), parseFloat(weight), parseFloat(height));
    }
}

function calculate(age, weight, height) {

}
```

Comment: If you have been struggling with this for hours, think how hard it is to figure out with no code or examples, just a vague description.

Comment: Learn some basic html/js coding.

Comment: Added code to the question.

Comment: do you mean something like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yCyj8/

Comment: The radio button can only return which element is selected. You could test the name of the selected element in an if statement that then sets the other variables.

Comment: I've noticed that you only have javascript code for reading age, weight, and height.  Do you know how to get the gender and activity level information from the form into the javascript program?  Is that what you need help with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
function validate() {
    var i , gender;
    var age = document.caloriecalc.age.value;
    var weight = document.caloriecalc.weight.value;
    var height = document.caloriecalc.height.value;

    for(i = 0; i < document.caloriecalc.gender.length; i++){
        if(document.caloriecalc.gender[i].checked){
            gender = document.caloriecalc.gender[i].value;
        }
    }

    if (age <= 0 || parseInt(age) != age) {
        alert("Please enter a valid age.");
    } else if (!gender) {
        alert("Please enter a valid gender.");
    } else if (weight <= 0 || isNaN(Number(weight))) {
        alert("Please enter a valid weight.");
    } else if (height <= 0 || isNaN(Number(height))) {
        alert("Please enter a valid height.");
    } else { //all the data has been validated
        calculate(parseInt(age), parseFloat(weight), parseFloat(height), gender);
    }
}

function calculate(age, weight, height, gender) {
    var a, x, y = 1, z = 1;
    switch(gender){
        case "male":
            a= 34;
            x =32;
            break;
        case "female":
            a= 10;
            x =20;
            break;
    }

    var bmr = a + (x * weight) + (y * height) - (z * age);
    document.getElementById('bmr').innerHTML = bmr;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yCyj8/)

Note: I don't know the value for `y` and `z` as you haven't mentioned them

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of radio button by using :-

```
 var lengthh=document.caloriecalc.gender.length;
 for(var i=0;i<lengthh;i++){
        if(document.caloriecalc.gender[i].checked){
            gender = document.caloriecalc.gender[i].value;
        }
    }
```

Now pass the values to calculate function and do you calculation as below :-

```
function calculate(age, weight, height, gender) {
    var a=0, x=0, y = 1, z = 1;
    if(gender=='male'){        
            a= 34;
            x =32;
           }else{
            a= 10;
            x =20;            
           }

    //Now the result is
    var resultt = a + (x * weight) + (y * height) - (z * age);
    document.getElementById('bmr').innerHTML = resultt;

}
```

Hope it will help you.